# How to output the result of a function into a string?

Tags: php, string, function, output

I have the following function:

```
function simulator () {
for($x = 0; $x <= 1000; $x++) {
    $var_1 = mt_rand(0,100);
    if ($var_1 <= 55) {
        $var_1 = " A";
        echo $var_1;
        $var_2 = mt_rand(0,100);
        if ($var_2 <= 52) {
            $var_2 = " A";
            echo $var_2;
            $var_3 = mt_rand(0,100);
            if ($var_3 <= 52) {
                $var_3 = " A";
                echo $var_3;
                $var_4 = mt_rand(0,100);
                if ($var_4 <= 48) {
                    $var_4 = " A";
                    echo $var_4;
                    $var_5 = mt_rand(0,100);
                    if ($var_5 <= 45) {
                        $var_5 = " A";
                            echo $var_5;
                        $var_6 = mt_rand(0,100);
                        if ($var_6 <= 42) {
                            $var_6 = " A";
                            echo $var_6;
                            $var_7 = mt_rand(0,100);
                                    if ($var_7 <= 29) {
                                            $var_7 = " A";
                                echo $var_7;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    echo " B";
  }
}

simulator();
```

But instead of displaying the results I want it to be made into one giant string.

Like `$string = simulator()`, but I know that won't work.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `return` statement

Comment: Start with `$out = '';`, replace every instance of `echo` in your function with `$out .=` and then at the end of your function, `return $out;`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable and add the results to it.

```
$result='';
$result.=do($something);
$result.=do($somethingElse);
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it to an array, then use implode.

```
function simulator () {
    $arr = [55, 52, 52, 48, 45, 42, 29];
    $out = [];
    for($x = 0; $x < 1001; $x++) {
        foreach($arr as $val) {
            $var = mt_rand(0,100);
            if ($var > $val) {
                $out[] = "B";
                continue 2;
            }
            $out[] = "A";
        }
    }
    return implode(" ", $out);
}

echo simulator();
```